# Trouble deploying one contract from another

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, constructor

Why creating a contract `new RewardCourts()` in another contract takes more than ten kilobytes of bytecode in the contract it is called from? (It makes bytecode too big and I can't deploy it!)

What to do to deploy one contract from another?

It is line 142 [here](https://github.com/vporton/courts/blob/8ba234cd56be70852d08589c2affabf0966c8eae/contracts/Template.sol#L142):

```
    function _installCourtWrapper(
        Kernel _dao
    )
        internal returns (CourtWrapper)
    {
        bytes32 _appId = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(apmNamehash("open"), keccak256("reward")));
        bytes memory initializeData = abi.encodeWithSelector(CourtWrapper(0).initialize.selector);
        CourtWrapper _wrapper = CourtWrapper(_installDefaultApp(_dao, _appId, initializeData));
//        _courtContract = new RewardCourts(); // takes too much bytecode
//        if (_courtContract != address(0) && _courtId == 0) {
//            _courtId = _courtContract.createCourt();
//        }
//        _wrapper.setCourt(_courtContract, _courtId);
        return _wrapper;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code in plain text here. No links or images.

Comment: That's a lot to wade through. The file you linked to doesn't contain `new RewardCourts()` and has less than 142 lines. Maybe revise that link. Also, please describe what chain you are trying to deploy to.

Comment: @RobHitchens-B9lab I've fixed the link. The code is long, I could not post it here. I am deploying to RPC on localhost.

Comment: Please post ONLY the relevant part then.

Comment: Are you using Remix?

Comment: @RobHitchens-B9lab No, I use command line with truffle inside.

Comment: Are you using ganache-cli? What ARE you using for the blockchain?

Comment: @RobHitchens-B9lab I use Aragon CLI, not sure if it uses Ganache. Not important now, my question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy a contract A from another contract C then C has to also include A bytecode.

A couple of alternatives:

- Use a factory contract F from C that will only deploy A so bytecode from A is included in F.
- Deploy contract A and make C deploy a delegate proxy that will reference existing contract A for bytecode, [EIP 1167](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1167).